# Estimate when a filesystem will be full

Tags: linux, monitoring, filesystems, capacity-planning

**Background**

I'm managing about 50 CentOS 5.6 Linux servers in my workplace with some critical filesystems that store weekly backups of applications, databases and user workplace files.

**Problem**

Last week, the /backup filesystem from 3 critical servers got filled and we lost valuable information from our internal application.

What I'm looking for is some kind of *predictive* solution/algorithm that can estimate a date in which the filesystem usage value is between 70% and 85%,so I can start worrying about the problem before it punches me in the face.

Comment: Do you have some form of monitoring in place? Have you tried Nagios? It can be set to any threshold and generate a warning state that a filesystem is becoming full.

Comment: We do have Nagios in place, but the time it takes to manage plus its lack of _prediction_ algorithms makes it harder to adapt __and maintain__